# Linux + Kernel panic

Tags: linux, kernel

when I reboot my Linux machine Linux version 5.5 red hat
I get the following warning on the console screen , 
Linux cant startup and I can't login

please advice , how to login as single user mode and how to bypass the following problem ?

```
umounting old /dev
umounting old /proc
umounting old /sys
switchroot: mount failed: No such file or directory
Kernel panic - not syncing: attempted to kill init!
```

Comment: It means the kernel (from `/boot`) and the initrd were loaded, but the root volume couldn't be found to replace the initrd.  We need more of the lines above what you show to diagnose this. Also, has anything changed which would cause this?

Comment: so - how to login as single user mode , as you know I cant access to the linux as usual

Comment: You can a) use rescue mode on the install CD, or b) boot from a Live CD, or c) boot from another hard disk. With the root disk dead or missing, this system cannot get to single-user mode.

Comment: did you have link to "how to create rescuew CD/DVD"

Comment: It's "on the install CD". You must already have one. If not, make another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to examine you system state is to use rescue mode of RHEL installation media. Just boot from CD or DVD and type `linux rescue`. [Here](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-rescuemode-boot.html) you can find more information about procedure.